# Video game save/load problems with python pickle (not loading instances)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, game-development

I'm currently working on a text adventure in python (this language just because it's the one I know), and I'm finding that creating and loading savefiles removes some of the mecahnics I've made. I'll include the problematic code here, rather than all of elements that work fine. it's mainly to do with classes and how instances are 'pickled'.

Here are some of the classes I've created:

```
class Player:
def __init__(self, name):
    self.sack = []
    self.kit = []
    self.equipped = []
    self.log = []
    self.done = []
class Weapon:
def __init__(self, name, price, minattack, maxattack):
    self.name = name
    self.price = price
    self.minattack = minattack
    self.maxattack = maxattack
class Food:
def __init__(self, name, price, healthadd):
    self.name = name
    self.price = price
    self.healthadd = healthadd
class Quest:
def __init__(self, name, requirement, num, gold, npc, place, give_text, prog_text, comp_text, done_text):
    self.name = name
    self.requirement = requirement
    self.num = num
    self.score = 0
    self.gold = gold
    self.npc = npc
    self.place = place
    self.give_text = give_text
    self.prog_text = prog_text
    self.comp_text = comp_text
    self.done_text = done_text
```

The instances in the Player class I've included here are just the ones that are appended by other mechanics with Weapons, Food and Quests. The code includes regions where Weapons, Food and Quests are populated (though working on a separate assets file might tidy things up a bit).

Here's how the save/load functions work currently:

```
def save(lastplace):
clear()
with open('savefile', 'wb') as f:
    PlayerID.currentplace = lastplace.name
    pickle.dump(PlayerID, f)     
    print("Game saved:\n")
    print(PlayerID.name)
    print("(Level %i)" % (PlayerID.level))
    print(lastplace.name)
    print('')
option = input(">>> ")
goto(lastplace)
def load():
clear()
if os.path.exists("savefile") == True:
    with open('savefile', 'rb') as f:
        global PlayerID
        PlayerID = pickle.load(f)
        savedplace = PlayerID.currentplace
        savedplace = locations[savedplace]
        goto(savedplace)        
else:
    print("You have no save file for this game.")
    option = input('>>> ')
    main()
```

It's worth noting that upon entry to the game, PlayerID (you) becomes a global variable. You might begin to see some of the issues here, or rather the overarching issue. Essentially, the pickling process serialises all of the possible class types stored in lists within the class of Player just get appended by their names, thus removing their class properties when loaded back into the game.

Is there a pythonic way to ensure that class instances are saved for a future load so that they can still behave as classes, particularly when stacked inside the class of Player? I appreciate this is more of an editorial rather than a question by its length, but any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: This post appears to have a lot of information unrelated to the problem. Can you please [edit] your question to make the problem clearer, ideally with a [mcve]? The question talks about "class types stored in lists within the class of Player", but it is unclear what is meant by that. Are "class types" classes, or instances (or, unlikely, metaclasses)? What is meant by "just get appended by their names" - are the "class types" appended by the class' name, or the name of instances? Why would this remove class properties? And as the code only defines instance attributes, which class properties?

Comment: Also, please revisit the formatting of your code. As Python is indentation sensitive and the ``class`` and ``def`` bodys are *not* indented in the question, every single code block has multiple syntax errors.